# Why am I getting different network traffic data from: Resource Monitor, Process Explorer, and Net Balancer?

Tags: networking, process-explorer

What am I reading wrong?

*(For simplicity I'm reporting 1B as 10b (one byte as 10 bits). These numbers are off by so much that this shouldn't matter)*

- **NetBalancer** shows about 20 KB/s or 200 K**b**/s or about **.2 Mb/s**
- **ResMon** shows **10** Mb/s
- **Process Explorer** (Sys Info) shows about 4.4 MB/s (or about **40
  Mb/s**

Screenshots below.

Am I missing something?
(And yes, I have accounted for the fact that NetBalancer reports in Bytes and RM reports  in Bits/second)
[image]

Comment: Did you run them all "as administrator"?

Comment: One hypothesis I can make is that some of these programs do not account for ALL of the traffic. Another would be that some take a lot longer than others to calculate over an average that stretches longer in time. So let's say that you downloaded a 10 MB file over one second. 10 MB/s for 1 sec. Yeah that's a fast connection. Anyway. Well program A could be using 0.25 sec to do its average, and so will display something pretty accurate. Program B, to be more stable over spikes and valleys, would use 2 seconds. It would come with the disadvantage of "smoothing" and flattening shorter transfers.